# Suspend main thread while calling background thread

Tags: android, kotlin

Is it possible in Kotlin to call some code from the main thread that blocks until that code completes but at the same time does not block the actual UI? From my understanding, coroutines might be able to do that through a process that "suspends" executing code on the main thread until the other thread completes. But I have no idea how to do that if it is even possible.

Comment: Yes, you can try Coroutines

Comment: Can't you just send a message to a handler or invoke a callback? Why do you feel the need to block the main thread?

Comment: first read: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads
then https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/threads
You can use aysnc task with kotlin just as with java. For Coroutines refer to https://developer.android.com/kotlin/coroutines

Comment: @Michael No, I don't want to block the main thread. I just want to suspend code at the point where the blocking code is called. I don't believe "suspending" and "blocking" are considered the same thing in Kotlin. I updated my title to be more accurate.

Comment: Afaik there is no "main thread" that you could block, apart from the ui thread. Do you mean that you want to execute several asynchronous tasks in sequence?

Comment: I assume this article should help you https://medium.com/@elizarov/blocking-threads-suspending-coroutines-d33e11bf4761

Comment: the main thread is the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

Coroutines are pretty easy. Import them:

```
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.2.2'
```

Make your first `async` code:

```
private val completableJob = Job() 
private val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + completableJob)
//you need these because you need to handle them with Android Lifecycle.

fun fireACoroutine(){
corotutineScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
     val someDataFromSuspendFunction = getStringAfterDelay()
     withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
       someTextView.text = someDataFromSuspendFunction 
      //switched to Main Thread.
     }
    }

   var x = 0
    x++ //you are outside of a coroutine
}

suspend fun getStringAfterDelay(): String = withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
     delay(1000)
     "Hello World"
   }
```

Don't forget the to clean your hands when in `Activity`/`Fragment`:

```
override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        completableJob.cancel()
    }
```

Done! I also have an article about coroutines: [Kotlin Coroutines, the non confusing one](https://medium.com/@stavro96/kotlin-coroutines-the-non-confusing-one-5a47ca799578)

I also suggest to know more about operators like `launch`, `async` or `runBlocking`.

Alternatively to coroutines, you may use `RxJava` to do what you request in questions. It does work in `Kotlin` like charm. Also, if you feel like you need to know more about both of them, stick to `AsyncTask`.

Comment: Can you modify your code to show some extra code that gets executed after the coroutineScope.launch and then explain when that extra line of code gets called? That is the most important part that is missing.

Comment: please recheck the question

Comment: I guess it wasn't clear, so I added the extra lines of code myself. The line with var x = 0. So when the code runs, does the code starting at x = 0 get executed even when someDataFromSuspendFunction is being called or does it only get called when the code inside withContext finishes?

Comment: the main focus is the `withContext` here. If you write code inside `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)`, you are not in the Main thread and with `launch` we are just suspending the Main thread to run that block. That happens until you write `withContext(Dispatchers.Main)`

Comment: You moved the code x = 0 to be inside the coroutine. That is not what I want. I want it as I had written it to understand whether it would execute after the code inside withContext completes. Please revert that and explain. Thanks.

Comment: I just added it inside a `fireACoroutine` method so you can understand better what's going on